# Is my logic correct in this proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove
Let {$B_i$}i∈ I and {$C_i$}i∈ I each be a family of mutually disjoint sets. If $B_i≈C_i$ for each i ∈ I, prove that
$\bigcup$$B_i$= $\bigcup$$C_i$

First I know this theorem is a general
version of

**7.8 Theorem Let A, B, C, and D be sets where A ∩ C = Ø and B ∩ D = Ø. If f : A → B and g : C → D are bijective functions, then f ∪ g is a bijective function A ∪ C → B ∪ D.**

I found that out in Lin’s book, Set Theory:An intuitive approach

Referenced Theorems

**7.6 Lemma** There exists an injective function f : A → B if and only if there exists a surjective function g : B → A.

**5.4 Theorem**

Let A be a set and let f:A$\mapsto$ B be a function;f:A$\mapsto$ B is surjective iff there exists a function g:B→A∋f $\circ$g=$1_B$

**AC (Axiom of Choice)**. Every set has a choice function

Proof attempt

Let $B_i \cap C_i =\emptyset$ for $i\in I$

There exists a function $f_i$:$B_i \mapsto C_i$ which is
bijective and function $g_i$:$C_i \mapsto B_i$

Now $B_i \subseteq P(B)$ ; $C_i \subseteq P(C)$ for i $\in$ I ,so that by AC,
B=$\bigcup B_i$ and C=$\bigcup C_i$
There exists a choice function$g_i$:B$\mapsto$ C where g(b)=$g_i(b)$ for an unique i for
b$\in$ B

To show the above is bijection use 5.4
and show it is an injection.
After this I am lost.I don’t know how to
create f$\cup$g assuming what I stated is
correct

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected.**

If $I$ is infinite you do need the axiom of choice to select a bijection $f_i$ for each $i\in I$, but after that it’s straightforward: just let $f=\bigcup_{i\in I}f_i$ and check that $f$ is a bijection from $\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ to $\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i$. For instance, suppose that $f(b)=c$ for some $b\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$. There is a unique $i_0\in I$ such that $b\in B_{i_0}$, and clearly $c=f(b)=f_{i_0}(b)\in C_{i_0}$. Now suppose that $f(b')=c$ for some $b'\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$; there is an $i_1\in I$ such that $b'\in B_{i_1}$. Then $c=f(b')=f_{i_1}(b')\in C_{i_1}$, and $C_{i_1}\cap C_{i_0}\ne\varnothing$ iff $i_0=i_1$, so $i_1=i_0$, and $b'\in B_{i_0}$. Finally, $f_{i_0}$ is a bijection, so $b'=b$, and $f$ is therefore injective. It’s even easier to verify that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @BrianMScott Look at TonyK’s comment, that is why I thought I was correct,if he stated otherwise I would not mention it...I came across this post as I was creating my title http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273266….. Let me guess you are saying theorem doesn’t need cause the family of sets are finite

Comment: @Eudoxus: My mistake: I read it carelessly and for some reason was thinking that you already had the bijections $f_i$, when in fact you had only that $|B_i|=|C_i|$. Yes, in that case you know that bijections exist, but you do need the axiom of choice to choose one for each $i\in I$ (unless, of course, $I$ is finite). I’ll correct the answer.

Comment: Thanx ,it is nice when I get things right.Me studying set theory 

Comment: @Eudoxus: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianMScott If I is finite then I don’t,because it is countable.

Comment: @Eudoxus: No, because it’s finite. You can make any finite number of arbitrary choices without the axiom of choice, but in general you can’t make infinitely many — even just countably infinitely many — without the axiom of choice.